# How to get previous state of nested form on clicking cancel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've nested RoR form. The nested form is in pop-up. The main form has one hyperlink, on click of it I'm making nested form visible. The nested form has radio buttons, text fields & 2 more actionable button (save & cancel). On click of cancel button, I need to restore data for dirty fields (fields which are modified) in nested form. How do I achieve this?

Here is my sample nested form code,

```
<%= form_for(@my_data,:validate => true) do |main_form| %> #It has save & cancel
  <%= main_form.fields_for :my_associated_data do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'associated_fields', :f => builder %> #associated_fields is the nested form - It has save & cancel. Need to restore data for this form on click of cancel.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Currently, when I modify the data in nested form, click on cancel and then click on link to open nested form, I see the data is dirty/modified. Can this be prevented?

**Note:** I need to persist values on click of nested form save.

Comment: Well you need to render associated_fields again or use js to put the default values again.

Comment: How will I handle `save` button, if I render `associated_fields` again? I need to persist those values. I don't want default values.

Comment: By default values means, values which were already stored. I assume, this is an update form right?

Comment: yes, update form. The problem still will be there. I mean, when I click on save in nested form, I need to get that data. Save click in nested form will not call update until I click on main form, that is the problem. I don't want to submit main form on click on save in nested form.

Comment: So load html in variable and then u can replace the html in Dom whenever u need old data.